# When is a function decorated, and when isn't a function decorated?

Tags: python, function, decorator

I have a decorator that records the functions present in my script:

```
registry=[]

def register(func):
    print('running register(%s)' % func)
    registry.append(func)
    return func
```

I then have a series of decorated functions:

```
@register
def func1():
    print('running f1')

@register 
def func2():
    print('running f2')
```

This works, after running the script, print(registry) returns:

```
[<function func1 at 0x0000000008433950>, <function func2 at 0x0000000008F06AE8>]
```

*However* calling the functions individually, for example:

```
func1()
```

Returns only '`running f1`': just the function, without the decoration.

I was expecting it to return something like `'running register( func1) \n running func1'`.

So my question is, when you have a decorated function and call it; when will it call the function in isolation and when will it call the decorated function?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we call a "decorator" is just [a higher order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), and the `@decorator` syntax nothing more than syntactic sugar so this:

```
@decorate
def func():
    pass
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
def func():
    pass

func = decorate(func)
```

As mentionned by Guillaume Deslandes, if this code is at your module or script's top-level, the decorator is only invoked when the module or script is first loaded by the runtime.

In your case, the decorator function `register` returns it's argument (the function it's applied to) unchanged, so calling the "decorated" function will work *exactly* as if it never had been decorated.

If you want to modify the decorated function in any way (by executing code before and or after the original function or whatever), you have to return a *new* function that will "replace" the original (but - usually - keeping a reference to the original function so this new "wrapper" function can still call the original), which is usually done [using the fact that Python functions are closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

```
def decorate(fun):
   def wrapper(*args, **kw):
       res = fun(*args, **kw)
       print("function {} called with *{}, *{} returned {}".format(fun, args, kw, res)
       return res

   return wrapper



@decorate
def fun(a):
    return a * 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `register` (decorator) function is only run once when the code is interpreted.

If you want to alter the function behaviour, try something like:

```py
def register(func):
    registry.append(func)
    print('adding register(%s)' % func)

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print('running register(%s)' % func)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrap
```

The first print is done once, the second one before each call.
Adding the arguments will make your decorator more transparent.

Comment: probably it be better to use `func.__name__`

Comment: or have fun with the `inspect` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html